# Obtaining a vector with sapply and use it to remove rows from dataframes in a list with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a list with dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = seq(1:10), name = LETTERS[1:10])
df2 <- data.frame(id = seq(11:20), name = LETTERS[11:20])
mylist <- list(df1, df2)
```

I want to remove rows from each dataframe in the list based on a condition (in this case, the value stored in column `id`). I create an empty vector where I will store the ids:

```
ids_to_remove <- c()
```

Then I apply my function:

```
sapply(mylist, function(df) {
  
  rows_above_th <- df[(df$id > 8),] # select the rows from each df above a threshold
  a <- rows_above_th$id # obtain the ids of the rows above the threshold 
  ids_to_remove <- append(ids_to_remove, a) # append each id to the vector
  
},

simplify = T

)
```

However, with or without `simplify = T`, this returns a matrix, while my desired output (`ids_to_remove`) would be a vector containing the `ids`, like this:

```
ids_to_remove <- c(9,10,9,10)
```

Because lastly I would use it in this way on single dataframes:

```
for(i in 1:length(ids_to_remove)){

                  mylist[[1]] <- mylist[[1]] %>%
                    filter(!id == ids_to_remove[i])

                }
```

And like this on the whole list (which is not working and I don´t get why):

```
i = 1
lapply(mylist, 
       function(df) {
         
                for(i in 1:length(ids_to_remove)){
                  df <- df %>%
                    filter(!id == ids_to_remove[i])
                           
                  i = i + 1
         
                }
} )
```

I get the errors may be in the `append` part of the `sapply` and maybe in the indexing of the `lapply`. I played around a bit but couldn´t still find the errors (or a better way to do this).

**EDIT:** original data has 70 dataframes (in a list) for a total of 2 million rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `sapply/lapply` you want to avoid trying to change the values of global variables. Instead, you should return the values you want. For example generate a vector if IDs to remove for each item in the list as a list

```
ids_to_remove <- lapply(mylist, function(df) {
  rows_above_th <- df[(df$id > 8),] # select the rows from each df above a threshold
  rows_above_th$id # obtain the ids of the rows above the threshold
})
```

And then you can use that list with your data list and `mapply` to iterate the two lists together

```
mapply(function(data, ids) {
  data %>% dplyr::filter(!id %in% ids)
}, mylist, ids_to_remove, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: This works perfectly and it was very clear. Thanks to your answer I also discovered that if I don't use `rows_above_th$id` in `function(df)` of `lapply` it returns the whole row of the df.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
 Map(\(x, y) subset(x, !id %in% y), mylist, ids_to_remove)
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer, sorry. `x` and `y` would be the two dataframes in the list? If I specify them with `Map(\(mylist[[1]])...` I get an error (`unexpected '[['`), and in any case I don't have `ids_to_remove`, as I was not able to obtain it as a vector. With that `for` loop, the ids are not being stored in `ids_to_remove`, and I cannot understand why. Moreover (my fault, I didn't specify it and now I updated the question), I have more than 2 dataframes in my original data list.

Comment: @LisaTedeschi The `x` is data.frame element from the mylist and `y` is the `ids_to_remove`.  I assume `ids_to_remove <- c(9, 10)` to remove each of the observation from the corresponding list element